# power available to a DC-DC step down atached to an ac power adapter

Tags: current, buck, converter

I have an AC-DC power adapter with output rated at 3.42A @ 19V and a Step Down Buck converter Xl4015 rated to manage up to 5A with 96% efficiency conected to the power adapter output.

What is the maximum current i´d have available at the end of the buck converter adjusted to output 12V?

Is there a math to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: The Xl4015 is a Buck converter IC, not a specific voltage converter. Your have to consult the datasheet for the specific product using the Xl4015 IC to know it's limits, but 5A @12v seems reasonable from what you've said.

Comment: Watts out = Watts in - loss. You want 60Watts output (5 x12) from just under 65Watts in. 4% of 65 is 2.6. So you just squeak it in.

Comment: user1850479 and Kartman the power convertion is what i´ve looking.  thank you !!!